# Rails Checkbox boolean values not passing to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, devise

Can't seem to get the checkbox to pass true to my database

this is the middle part of my devise sign-up form.

```
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= check_box_tag :admin, checked = true %>
    <%= label_tag :admin %>
  </div>
```

I've set the admin field to default to false in my schema.rb when Null

I don't know where else to start.

If you guys need any screenshots of controllers, etc.

Please comment :)

Answer (score 0):

**update**

```
<%= check_box_tag :admin, nil, checked: true %>
```

<%= %> is ruby code, not html

maybe this documatation is helpful for you

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.6 and Bootstrap 4

I still can not find the reason why some form.check_box work like booleans and interact in a good way with the model. But in my little experience, and in some cases works with checked_value = "1" and unchecked_value = "0".
Maybe someone with more experienced could clarify this issue. For now, this solved my problem:

```
<%= form.check_box :admin,{class:"form-check-input", type:"checkbox"}, true, false %>
<%= form.label :admin,'Is an admin account?', class:"form-check-label" %>
```

Source:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=checkbox

It is also important to be clear and review the [strong params](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), adding :admin

Hope this helps, it was for me, I would like to explain more in detail, but I am new at this topic.